# Necessary and sufficient conditions for a transition matrix to have a limit

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains, spectral-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $T$ be an $n \times n$ transition matrix, i.e. the rows sum to 1 and the entries all lie in the interval $[0,1]$. What are necessary and sufficient conditions for which the limit $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} T^{n}$ exists?

I recall reading somewhere (but don't remember where) that this is true if and only if $1$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ with geometric multiplicity 1, and all other eigenvalues have length strictly less than 1. But this does not seem to be true, for the following matrix:

```
    [0, 0.5, 0.5 , 0   , 0   , 0  , 0  ],
    [0, 0  , 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0  , 0  ],
    [0, 0  , 0   , 1   , 0   , 0  , 0  ],
    [0, 0  , 0   , 0   , 0.5 , 0.5, 0  ],
    [0, 0  , 0   , 0   , 0   , 0  , 1  ],
    [0, 0  , 0.5 , 0   , 0   , 0  , 0.5],
    [0, 0  , 0   , 1   , 0   , 0  , 0  ]
```

According to MATLAB, the limit of its powers appears to converge to:

```
         0         0    0.1663    0.1650    0.0825    0.0825    0.4988
         0         0    0.0825    0.3300    0.1650    0.1650    0.2475
         0         0         0    1.0000         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0    0.5000    0.5000         0
         0         0    0.2500         0         0         0    0.7500
         0         0    0.2500         0         0         0    0.7500
         0         0         0    1.0000         0         0         0
```

Yet its eigenvalues are $1,0,-0.5000 + 0.8660i,-0.5000 - 0.8660i$ the last two of which have length strictly equal to 1.

Comment: The condition is not for the transition matrix to converge (obviously if $T$ is the identity matrix then $T^n$ converges, but does not satisfy the conditions), but instead for $T^n \mu$ to converge to the invariant distribution (the normalized eigenvector with eigenvalue 1) for any "probability vector" $\mu$.

Comment: Also, the limit of the powers of this matrix does not converge; there is a periodic pattern with period 3. You probably did not notice because you were looking at $T^{100}$, $T^{1000}$, $T^{10000}$, and so on which are all $1$ modulo $3$.

Comment: Could be rounding error. The last two eigenvalues do have length exactly one, but your four-decimal approximations have length $0.999978$ (when rounded to six places), which is strictly less than one.

Comment: Any thoughts on the comments, 308485?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is not responsive to comments.